# (SQL SCRIPT + SQL SERVER 2005) Weird '-' symbols

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I was writing a SQL script like the following for SQL server 2005:

```
select '============================'
select '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
select char(13) + 'Control 127232:'
exec xp_loginconfig
go
```

I noticed that there is a '-' symbols after my string of 'select '============================'' and also after my string of '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'.

Sample output:

```
============================

-
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

-

Control 127232:
```

I would like to remove this '-' symbols if possible?

thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: i see. will work on it once there is a suitable answer coming up! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps instead of `SELECT`ing this information, you would be more interested in [`PRINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)ing it.

Comment: this is a Trans-SQL statement language. it doesnt support print :(